# XCode 4 - Snapshot Error - .gitignore ignores .DS_Store

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4, snapshot

```
**Unable to create snapshot**

The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:

/path/to/project/.DS_Store

Use -f if you really want to add them

fatal: no files added
```

thats the error i get any ideas?!? google a lot all the snapshot problems didn't seem to fit on my error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the .DS_STORE ( they are not really needed, they store Finder releated meta data).

Use some command like:

```
sudo find /path/to/project -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: wow i should have been able to figure this one out ;-) i knew that they stored metadata... i thought it was some git problem^^

Comment: This will, however, destroy whatever file metadata you have in your project, which will change the way it appears when browsing via Finder.  The files will also be re-created whenever you access them via the Finder.  Perhaps a good workaround to get past the hump of the "snapshot" issue, though.  Not entirely satisfying, in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove `.DS_STORE` from your gitignore config (although it really should be ignored because you dont want this useless file in your repo) by removing it from the file at `~/.gitignore` or `/Users/YOU/.gitignore`.

Comment: yeah but i have tons of files that need to be ignored.... deleting it fixed the problem but still thanks